# How to setup multiple OpenVPN connections on a server for a single localhost app to use on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: networking, centos, routing, openvpn, centos6

I have a scenario where I need to run several OpenVPN connections at one time and to allow a singular application to access each of these connections.

How wold I go about starting up several OpenVPN connections at one time and then uniquely connect to each one?

In my scenario I need to make requests to each of these several connections randomly for the application's network requests.  I also then will be stopping and starting OpenVPN connections at minutely or every few minutes so as to obtain a fresh IP.

One of the "tricky" parts perhaps that worries me most is that I need to make sure that I do not munge up normal traffic on this server since I have about 20 IP addresses for various web sites running on it and other apps (services) running as well.  I need to fire up these OpenVPN connections such that I can specifically allow this singular application to utilize these connections in a random fashion.  I am not entirely sure on how I will do this such that I can identify each of the OpenVPN connections separately for usage.

I was contemplating accomplishing this via EC2 instances as I have done before, but then realized that perhaps I can work around this by establishing all of the connections on a singular server since I don't need to worry about high levels of bandwidth.  From what I have read, it seems doable, but I've not yet put the details together for this and wanted to make sure I get moving in right direction before pulling up my sleeves.

Comment: What you are describing sounds very much like spammy/scammy behavior.  Trying to route things per application is a big PITA.  Sticky with your EC2 setup, or going with LXC, or some other VM/container type approach would probably be a lot easier.

Comment: @Zoredache I really would like to get this scenario working and eliminate the EC2 setup.  I have been using that for some time and it is just too costly and this provides a much more cost effective solution for this scenario.  Fortunately this is neither a spam nor scam scenario.

Comment: I did mention LXC as an option, which should work on a single EC2 instance. Ignoring that you basically falling into the multiple wan setup, with each VPN acting as a WAN link.  See: http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: @Zoredache so I really liked you're suggestion about using LXC's.  I essentially had this working via `docker`, but now am getting an `openvpn Tainted` panic when firing them off on CentOS 6.5 oddly enough.  Same error, it would seem, in an OpenVZ CentOS 5 bug report, even though I'm not using OpenVZ.  <sigh> But looks nice in theory and we had a great dockfile built up for it as well that worked okay on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to try to asking another question about that specific issue, and include some specifics details. Perhaps someone else has some insight.